# ZQ210 printing zpl as text and not changing device.languages

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have a ZQ210 and I am trying to print the following command with ZPL

```
^XA^F0100,100^BY3
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD2020100020003000^XZ
```

After trying out different techniques to print, I discovered that my printer is in line feed mode, so I followed the manual and used Zebra Setup Utility and checked if it supported it with  `! U1 getvar "allcv"` the output had this

```
netmanage.
zpl.
scanner.
line_print.
line_print.buffer_height : 32767 , Choices: 412-32767
apl.
ezpl.
ezpl.power_up_action : feed , Choices: feed,no motion
ezpl.head_close_action : no motion , Choices: feed,no motion
```

So I followed [this tutorial](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/how-to-enable-zpl-or-line-print-mode-on-mobile-printers.html), and my printer still doesn't print ZPL, infact when I try the recalibrate command on it it simply prints the zpl as text.

Comment: On page 8 of the [printer manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/mobile/zq210/P1106453-01EN-ZQ210-ug-en.pdf) it says: *This printer uses CPCL programming language. To create and print labels using this language, refer to the Programming Guide for CPCL (p/n P1073699-001).* Your printer does not support ZPL to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 8 of [the printer manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/mobile/zq210/P1106453-01EN-ZQ210-ug-en.pdf) it says

> This printer uses CPCL programming language.

The ZQ210 does not accept ZPL, printing with CPCL worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27855320)

Comment: @WilliMentzel This answers the question exactly, and this is the OP self-answering.

Comment: @GSerg Please see the edit history. I reviewed another version of this answer (which was more like a comment) and missed the fact that the OP is self-answering. Now it is indeed a good answer.